# Проблема с клонированием отдельной ветки github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

проблема заключается в том, что я не могу клонировать удалённый репозиторий к себе в папку. Час в интернете искал, как склонировать только ветку, нашёл, но в итоге всё-равно ничего. *Что я делаю не так?*

***Задача***:

```
Продолжите работу над предыдущим заданием:
Подмерджите к ветке master ветку удаленного репозитория hat и локальную ветку boots_buttons.
Сравните получившуюся ветку master и удаленную ветку demo — чем они отличаются?
```

***Условие прошлой задачи***:

```
Последовательно выполните следующее задания:
Перейдите в домашнюю директорию и создайте папку git_lab1_lesson2, перейдите в эту папку.
Склонируйте себе репозиторий https://github.com/YandexLyceum/human.git
Просмотрите список всех веток репозитория
Просмотрите содержимое файла human.txt
Сравните содержимое файла human.txt в ветке master с каждой из веток, которые вы видите. Попробуйте использовать git diﬀ с 1 параметром и с 2 параметрами
Создайте ветку boots_buttons от ветки master, переключитесь в неё
Слейте в новую ветку ветки boots и buttons.
Возникли-ли конфликты на предыдущем этапе? Почему?
Переключитесь на ветку master
```

***Мой код по второй задаче***

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/YandexLyceum/human.git -b hat
  Cloning into 'human'...
  remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
  remote: Total 24 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 24
  Unpacking objects: 100% (24/24), 2.02 KiB | 19.00 KiB/s, done.

 $ git branch
  boots_buttons
* master
```

в конце последней команды можно заметить, что ни demo, а уж тем более hat не склонировались. Пробовал несколько раз втечение часа.

Comment: Не вижу команды `cd human`

Comment: А самое главное, в этой задаче вообще не надо ничего клонировать

Comment: @AlexeyTen , "ветку удаленного репозитория hat", его не было до этого, где тогда его взять?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , да, благодарю, нужно было прописать cd human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dmitriy@ah531:~/git-demo$ git clone https://github.com/YandexLyceum/human.git
Cloning into 'human'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Total 24 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 24
Unpacking objects: 100% (24/24), done.    
dmitriy@ah531:~/git-demo$ cd human
dmitriy@ah531:~/git-demo/human$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/boots
  remotes/origin/buttons
  remotes/origin/demo
  remotes/origin/hat
  remotes/origin/master
dmitriy@ah531:~/git-demo/human$ git checkout hat 
Branch 'hat' set up to track remote branch 'hat' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'hat
```

Дальше резберетесь?